# Is there a way to retrieve the full assembly execution trace of a C program?

Tags: c, assembly, trace

I have a couple C programs that I basically want to disassemble. I was using objdump, but I realized that is static disassembly. Is there anyway to get the full **assembly-level** trace of the program of the instructions executed **in order**? I am running on x86-64.

Comment: That's the purpose of a debugger.

Comment: or a simulator.

Comment: as soon as you hit a conditional branch (that relies on something outside the program) then your execution order disassembly ends

Comment: Wait, you don't want a call stack backtrace, you want every instruction in execution order?  Your tags and title are using terminology that matches GDB's `bt` command.  But what you actually want is an execution trace, not just the stack. Please [edit] your question to remove the "stack" stuff if that's not what you want.

Comment: For a full dynamic-order trace, tools like Intel SDE or other dynamic instrumentation tools, or a debugger, or possibly `perf` with intel-pt to record this with HW support for less overhead, if you have a CPU that supports that.

Comment: the tools can only do so much for you, debuggers can affect how the program runs, hiding the real bug.  Or are otherwise misleading.  Modifying the program to help the tools can hide the bug or move it.  At the end of the day you often have to read the code and find the bug visually.  You have not specified the architecture, also understanding that for variable length instruction sets like x86 you cant rely on the disassembler to provide a correct disassembly.

Comment: I edited my question to remove the stack stuff. Yes, I basically just want the assembly execution instructions in order. If I have to simulate them or use a debugger, is there a way to dump that information to a file?

Comment: I have used 'gdb where' a lot, on production core dumps in a cron script that emailed me the result, and it is good on code test runs, too.  https://condor.depaul.edu/glancast/373class/docs/gdb.html

Comment: [Gdb process record/replay execution log](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5515216) mentions GDB's `record save filename` command

Comment: [How to run record instruction-history and function-call-history in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22507169) has some details about GDB using hardware support like intel-pt, instead of slowly single-stepping each instruction.

Comment: Multithreaded apps could be problematic.....:)

Comment: Many apps run for years.  Trace file may get large....

Comment: You may want to take a look at PIN (https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool.html) or DynamoRIO (https://dynamorio.org/).  I believe either tool can dump instructions during an execution.  You may need to write the tool do perform the exact instrumentation

Comment: Yes, I am specifically looking for a program that just takes in my executable and spits out the full unrolled execution trace in a file. I haven't had much lucky trying gdb or perf with intel-pt. I am trying PIN now, but it just seems to be running forever. If there's not a straightforward way to get the execution trace, I'll have to stick with objdump.

Comment: Traces are huge and slow to generate (especially just single-stepping with a debugger); most programs include loops.  Test on a very simple statically-linked program that just exits.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to retrieve the full stack trace/execution trace of a C program at the assembly level?

The call stack might not even exist. Some C implementations could (in *some* simple cases) inline every function call and work in registers (but [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) shows that this is not always possible). That might happen with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) doing whole-program link-time optimizations (e.g. invoked [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) `gcc -O3 -flto -fwhole-program` for both compilation and linking steps)

However, if you use Linux/x86-64 and if you want to retrieve at runtime the call stack, consider using Ian Taylor's [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace). It is part of *some* recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compilers.

> Is there anyway to get the full assembly-level trace of the program of the instructions executed in order?

Alternatively, use and/or patch some processor emulator like [Qemu](https://www.qemu.org/).